# compare variables and remove one with lowest value R

Tags: r, correlation, random-forest, r-caret

I have a dataframe of the correlation between 45 variables, and have added the the random forest importance value given to each by the 'varImp' function (I ran a random forest training model with this data.

I would like to run through each column, and wherever a variable has a correlation over .8 (in absolute terms), **remove either that row variable or that column variable, whichever has the lower 'varImp' importance**. I would also like to remove the same variable from the column/row (since it's a correlation matrix, all variables show up in both a row and a column).

For example, roll_belt and max_picth_belt have a correlation of ~.97, and because roll_belt has a value of 3.77 compared to max_picth_belt's 3.16, I would like to delete max_pitch_belt both as a row, and as a column.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it sounds a job for `apply` but the picture you posted is useless. Do post a `dput` of a piece of your data not a picture.

Comment: Please add your actual data and show desired output.

Comment: Sorry about that, here's a google doc of the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sT6M7hIQcTM_sh2YhkK_uZAq6ZjLksCvLtRhtQR19v8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please put a dput of the data, so people can get to the data with the least amount of trouble.

Comment: The desired output would be like this google dog : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L18SJ4t1A4qNMAvZinH1ovb9fZH8lFGZmBk06-DUois/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If the goal of the exercise is to avoid multicollinearity in you model, may be a better way would be to use [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there must be a more straightforward way. Still, my code does the job.

Assume, we've loaded your dataset into an object called `df` (I do not include the code to get your data as it is not relevant).

First, it's handy to  I split the data itself and the `value` column that is used for testing feature importance. New object called `test.value` is the 46-th column.

```
test.value <- df$value
df <- df[,-ncol(df)] # remove the last column from the dataset
```

Now we are ready to start.

The framework. We need to identify the numbers of rows/columns to remove from the dataset. So we will:

1. go column by column
2. identify the positions of all correlates bigger than 0.8
3. compare feature importance one by one in a nested loop
4. record the row/column numbers that should be removed in an object
   `remove`
5. finally, remove the chosen rows/columns

The code is:

```
remove <- c() # a vector to store features to be removed
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
        coli <- df[,i] # pick up i-th column
        highcori <- coli>.8 & coli!=1 # logical vector of cors > 0.8

        # go further only if there are cors > 0.8
        if(sum(highcori,na.rm = T)>0){

        posi <- which(highcori) # identify positions of cors > 0.8

        # compare feature importance one by one
        for(k in 1:length(posi)){
                remi <- ifelse(test.value[i]>test.value[posi[k]],posi[k],i)
                remove <- c(remove,remi) # store the less valued feature 
                }
        }

}

remove <- sort(unique(remove)) # keep only unique entries

df.clean <- df[-remove,-remove] # finally, clean the dataset
```

That's it.

---

UPDATE
For those who can provide a better solution, here are the data in an easily readable form, [cor.remove.RData](https://yadi.sk/d/H8LvJ3eAiSUrm)
OR
if you prefer `dput`
[dput.df.txt](https://yadi.sk/i/XzCPk1HgiSUui)
[dput.test.value.txt](https://yadi.sk/i/r21S32zBiSUuk)

I would be interested to see a better way of solving the task.

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry if I worded this post poorly/didnt include the data properly. Your code works, though I made a few edits. Since it's a correlation matrix, everything is going to have 100% correlation with itself, so I changed the 'highcori' definition to     `highcori <- ifelse(coli>=.8 & coli!= 1, TRUE,FALSE)`, and added `if(i!=k)` here       `if(i!=k){
                remi <- ifelse(test.value[i]>test.value[posi[k]],posi[k],i)
                remove <- c(remove,remi)`

Comment: Reasonable improvements.   
Sorry, I forgot to include in the answer the step when I change all self-correlations for NAs. That's what I've done. Surely, the conditioning like `if(coli>=.8 & coli!= 1)` makes much more sense. Note that you don't need `ifelse` since `coli>=.8 & coli!= 1` produces just the desired output.